# How to find reason for StackOverflowException in System.Web.dll after upgrading an ASP.NET MVC 2 project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, upgrade

I've upgraded an ASP.NET MVC 2 solution to MVC 4*. When running the site the start page is displayed but after a little while a StackOverflowException is thrown in System.Web.dll (sometimes in System.Runtime.Serialization.dll) and thus there's no call stack to examine. I've stepped through the start sequence code but haven't found anything suspicious.
What should I do to find the problem?

*Tried both manual variants described [here](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes#upgrading) and [here](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253806) as well as automatic variants using [this](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/59008) and [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UpgradeMvc3ToMvc4) tool

Comment: You can try to attach to the framework source code for debugging, resharper can do this easily.

Comment: @bateloche's suggestion will probably be made easier by following this link: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/ :)

Comment: Have you tried adding System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch(); in your application start in the global.asax.cs for any startup issues?

Comment: Through **Testing Random Stuff Driven Development** I tested to insert a closing cell tag (</td>) on the page where the stackoverflow exception occurred (all other cells had closing tags) which made the error go away! Happy that it worked but I'm left in the dark.

Comment: @Christian I had the same problem today, also getting exceptions in either System.Web.dll or System.Runtime.Serialization.dll a few seconds AFTER the page is displayed as a result of a GET request. I figured out this was due to a malformed closing tag (actually, there was an opening <tbody> tag instead of a closing </tbody> tag in one place). Fixing this made the problem go away. I don't feel this is really a proper answer, so I'm posting it as a comment.

Comment: Same here ... thank God I found your comments and found unclosed `td` tag then.

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38743393/2843612), it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

My Hint:
If your page is formatting correctly, look at right before each `</tr>` and see if you are missing a `</td>`