# Stackoverflow exception in VS 2015 but not in VS2010 how?

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015, stack-overflow

There is a webservice project written in VS2010 few years ago and the problem is all code exactly same (same PC , Tested with vs2010 and 2015 with the same code) but in vs2015 it gives error on debug mode. Options  > "Projects & Solutions" settings are all same. I took this error and definition of it;

An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Runtime.Serialization.dll

System.StackOverflowException was unhandled Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Anyone have idea about it , I'm really glad to attention. I could't share code because it's nearly 30.000 lines.

Comment: How could we possibly figure out what's happening without seeing the code where it's being thrown?  Specifically the line where the exception hits?  Have you even tried debugging it to observe the behavior that leads to the exception?

Comment: I try to comment or delete different part of 30.000 lines many times  but it popup same error everytime.  When I start Debug  , not doing anything about functions , it gives error

Comment: So set it to break on the exception, and then look at the call stack...

Comment: btw stackoverflow exception don't point a line. it point dll file

Comment: When you get an exception in visual studio, you can set it to break on the exception by going "debug > exceptions" and checking "thrown" next to "common language runtime exceptions".  It will break on the line where the SO exception occurs, and then just look at the call stack to see which methods are being called over and over again.

Comment: @rory.ap Not if it's the Browser Link option causing the issue which it was for me... Totally silent SO exception with no call stack and no clue as to what was causing it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**SOLVED**

Add this to the appSettings in your web.config:

```
<add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="false" />
```

After VS 2013, by default VS automatically enables Browser Link. The StackOverflowException occurs, but doesn't include any details of what happened. You can check this link for more information about the browser link feature in VS 2013: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/06/28/browser-link-feature-in-visual-studio-preview-2013/

Comment: Works like a charm :) I guess only setback of setting this feature to false is that client script can not be debugged in visual studio?

Answer (score 0):

You got this error, what you gonna do ....

Your project stops and not working, but that is usually not about your code.

Of course, that depends how you coding but if you didn’t write any infinite loop than its completely fine.

It’s about Visual Studio 2013, it  tries to send long serialized data to browser because of “**enable browser link**” option.

You can fix this issue by two ways..

Add this in appSettings in your web.config

```
<add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="false" />
```

Or

You can disable following option in tool menu

[image: Click here]